# Obtaining the average red, green, blue values within grid cells in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Is there a way to obtain the average red, green, blue values within grid cells in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Deos grid cells has a layer or did you add them using "View > Decoration > Grid"?

Comment: Grid is a layer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Zonal Statistics** tool.

[image]

Comment: Nice work that solved the problem.  Thanks.